# Hypersurface Orthogonality of Conformal Killing field on Conformal Killing Horizon

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensor-calculus

Suppose we have a spacetime manifold $(\mathcal{M},g)$ admitting a conformal Killing Horizon $\mathcal{H}_c$ generated by a conformal Killing field $\chi^a$ (which is null only on the conformal Killing horizon). The conformal killing field is defined by the equation,
\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{L}_{\chi}g_{ab} = 2 \psi g_{ab} ~,
\end{equation}
where $\psi$ is a scalar field. The norm of $\chi$ is zero exactly only on $\mathcal{H}_c$ i.e $\chi^a \chi_a \overset{\mathcal{H}_c} = 0$. The conformal Killing field is a null geodesic generator of the conformal killing horizon and hence satisfies,
\begin{equation}
\chi^a \nabla_a \chi_b \overset{\mathcal{H}_c} = \kappa \chi_b ~,
\end{equation}
where $\kappa$ is the non-affinity parameter of the null geodesic generator $\chi^a$. My question is whether $\chi^a$ is hypersurface orthogonal to the conformal Killing horizon, i.e whether we have the validity of the statement that,
\begin{equation}
\chi_{[a} \nabla_b \chi_{c]} \overset{\mathcal{H}_c} = 0 ~?
\end{equation}
The last result would have been been true had $\chi^a$ been a Killing vector field generating a Killing Horizon. Any help or references towards this would be very helpful.